# Pytorch: RuntimeError: Expected to have finished reduction in the prior iteration before starting a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am training a multilingual bert model for a sentiment classification task. I have 2 GPUs on 1 Machine so I am using Huggingface `Accelerator` for distributed training. But when I run the code it throws a Runtime Error.

### Model

```
class BERTModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BERTModel, self).__init__()
        self.bert = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
        self.bert_drop = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(768 * 2, 1) # *2 since we have 2 pooling layers

    def forward(self, ids, mask, token_type_ids):
        o1, _ = self.bert(
            ids, 
            attention_mask=mask, 
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids
        )
        
        mean_pooling = torch.mean(o1, 1)
        max_pooling, _ = torch.max(o1, 1)
        cat = torch.cat((mean_pooling, max_pooling), 1)
        
        bo = self.bert_drop(cat)
        output = self.out(bo)
        return output
```

### Train Function

```
def train_fn(data_loader, model, optimizer, scheduler):
    
        
        """
        Training Function for the Model
        
        parameters: data_loader - PyTorch DataLoader
                    model - The Model to be used for training
                    optimizer - The Optimizer to be used for training
                    scheduler - The Learning Rate Scheduler 
                    
        returns: None
        """
        accelerator = Accelerator()

        model, optimizer, data_loader = accelerator.prepare(model, optimizer, data_loader)
        model.train()

        for bi, d in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=len(data_loader)):
            ids = d["ids"]
            token_type_ids = d["token_type_ids"]
            mask = d["mask"]
            targets = d["targets"]

            
            ids = ids.to(torch.long)
            token_type_ids = token_type_ids.to(torch.long)
            mask = mask.to(torch.long)
            targets = targets.to(torch.float)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(ids=ids, mask=mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)

            loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
            
            if bi % 1000 == 0:
                print(f"bi={bi}, loss={loss}")

            accelerator.backward(loss)
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/accelerate/notebook_launcher.py in notebook_launcher(function, args, num_processes, use_fp16, use_port)
    107             try:
    108                 print(f"Launching a training on {num_processes} GPUs.")
--> 109                 start_processes(launcher, nprocs=num_processes, start_method="fork")
    110             finally:
    111                 # Clean up the environment variables set.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py in start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method)
    156 
    157     # Loop on join until it returns True or raises an exception.
--> 158     while not context.join():
    159         pass
    160 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py in join(self, timeout)
    117         msg = "\n\n-- Process %d terminated with the following error:\n" % error_index
    118         msg += original_trace
--> 119         raise Exception(msg)
    120 
    121 

Exception: 

-- Process 1 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 20, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/accelerate/utils.py", line 274, in __call__
    self.launcher(*args)
  File "<timed exec>", line 276, in run
  File "<timed exec>", line 74, in train_fn
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 726, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/amp/autocast_mode.py", line 135, in decorate_autocast
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 585, in forward
    self.reducer.prepare_for_backward([])

RuntimeError: Expected to have finished reduction in the prior iteration before 
starting a new one. This error indicates that your module has parameters that 
were not used in producing loss. You can enable unused parameter detection by (1) 
passing the keyword argument `find_unused_parameters=True` to 
`torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel`; (2) making sure all `forward`
 function outputs participate in calculating loss. If you already have done the 
above two steps, then the distributed data parallel module wasn't able to locate
 the output tensors in the return value of your module's `forward` function. 
Please include the loss function and the structure of the return value of 
`forward` of your module when reporting this issue (e.g. list, dict, iterable).
```

Comment: Any resolution to this man? Been 2 years since you asked this and I'm still facing this exact error